# Figure out the commits with respect to a determined line code - Git Extensions OR visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, git-extensions

In Git Extensions OR Visual Studio, is it possible to query the historical commits applied on a specified line of code?
for example, I have a line (or couple of consecutive lines) in a very big code file (> 20k lines) and I need to know by which commits those lines are added/changed?

Based on my best knowledge, there is a way to query the historical commits regarding one file, by going to the file under the file tree, right click and view history. Is there a way to filter out from those commits, the ones that have modifications on my interesting lines?

Comment: Do you mean "blame" or "annotate"?

Answer (score 4):

In the file history dialog you can switch to the "Blame" tab and then see which (last) commits changed which lines.
From there you can blame previous revisions.[image]